# Network Communication Adapter

Tags: c#, networking

I'm creating a internet connection utility and below is the code I have used.
Is there any better way of check for proxy and internet connection etc?

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Check the Internet connection using the url passed into it
    /// Network Adapter Check - TRUE
    /// Proxy Settings Check - TRUE
    /// Speed Check - Depends on Parameter speedCheck
    /// Internet Connection Check - TRUE
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">Url to validate connection</param>
    /// <param name="speedCheck">Validate Speed of Interenet Connection </param>
    /// <returns>Connection/No Connection</returns>        
    public static bool CheckInternet(string url, bool speedCheck)
    {
        speedCheckRequired = speedCheck;
        setProgressBar("Internet Connection", "Validation", 4);
        bool present = validateConnection(url);
        closeProgressBar();

        return present;
    }

 /// <summary>
    /// Check for proxy setting and if pressent gather proxy details
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="web">WebClient Obeject</param>
    /// <returns>Setting Found/Not Found</returns>
    public static bool IsProxyRequired(string testUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            progressBar.SetStatus("Quering for proxy settings");                
            HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(testUrl);                
            IWebProxy proxy = myWebRequest.Proxy;
            var settings = proxy.GetProxy(myWebRequest.RequestUri);                
            if (!settings.OriginalString.Equals(testUrl))
            {
                Utilities.DebugSolution.SetMessage("Utilities.NetworkCommunication.IsProxyRequired","Proxy setting found");
                Utilities.DebugSolution.SetMessage("Utilities.NetworkCommunication.IsProxyRequired", String.Format("Url: {0} Port: {1}",settings.AbsoluteUri,settings.Port));
                proxySettings = proxy;
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Utilities.NetworkCommunication.IsProxyRequired Exception: " + e.Message.ToString());
            Utilities.DebugSolution.SetException("Utilies.NetworkCommunication.IsProxyRequired", e);
        }


        return false;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Make sure there is a network connection on the device
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="status"></param>
    /// <returns>Connected/Not Connected</returns>
    public static bool IsNetorkAdapterConnected(ref string status)
    {
        bool result = false;
        status = "Network adapter not connected";
        try
        {
            progressBar.SetStatus("Quering network connections");  
            if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                result = true;
                status = String.Empty;
            }

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Utilities.NetworkCommunication.IsNetorkAdapterConnected Exception: " + e.Message.ToString());
            Utilities.DebugSolution.SetException("Utilies.NetworkCommunication.IsNetorkAdapterConnected", e);
        }
        return result;
    }



    private static bool validateConnection(string url)
    {
        string status = String.Empty;
        if (IsNetorkAdapterConnected(ref status))
        {


            try
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    if (IsProxyRequired(url))
                        client.Proxy = proxySettings;

                    try
                    {
                        progressBar.SetStatus("Checking internet connection");           
                        using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
                            return CheckSpeed(String.Empty);

                    }catch
                    {
                        ///This Catch says there is no internet connection available.
                        ///So no login\debug set here!
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Utilities.NetworkCommunication.validateConnection Exception: " + e.Message.ToString());
                Utilities.DebugSolution.SetException("Utilies.NetworkCommunication.validateConnection", e);
            }

        }//END if (IsNetorkAdapterConnected(ref status))

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you posting just a collection of methods, instead of a whole class? Or is this just a part of some class?

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <returns>Connection/No Connection</returns>
```

When a method returns `bool`, you should make it very clear what do the `true` and `false` values mean. The intention is pretty clear here, but if it was e.g.:

```
/// <returns>Ascending/Descending</returns>
```

that would confuse me a lot. Documentation shouldn't make you guess.

---

```
setProgressBar("Internet Connection", "Validation", 4);
bool present = validateConnection(url);
closeProgressBar();
```

What happens when `validateConnection` throws an exception that is handled higher up the call stack? I think it will leave the progress bar open, but stuck.

One way to fix this would be to make `setProgressBar` return `IDisposable` and then use `using`. This has the added advantage that you don't need the local `present` anymore:

```
using (setProgressBar("Internet Connection", "Validation", 4))
{
    return validateConnection(url);
}
```

Also, if you have two methods that logically form a pair, their names should form a pair too. Consider names like open/close, enable/disable, or maybe set/reset.

---

```
/// <param name="web">WebClient Obeject</param>
```

This method doesn't have any such parameter. You should always make sure that your documentation and your code match.

Also, I believe that no documentation is better than useless documentation. Saying that the parameter of type `WebClient` is an "WebClient Obeject" doesn't tell the user of your code anything new.

---

```
/// <param name="status"></param>
```

Similar to above: if you don't want to document the parameter, don't, remove this line completely.

---

```
public static bool IsNetorkAdapterConnected(ref string status)
```

This method doesn't read `status`, so it should be an `out` parameter, instead of `ref`. That way, the signature more clearly documents what the method does and the callers of this method also won't have to assign some default value to their `status` local variable.

---

```
bool result = false;
status = "Network adapter not connected";
try
{
    progressBar.SetStatus("Quering network connections");  
    if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
    {
        result = true;
        status = String.Empty;
    }

}catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Utilities.NetworkCommunication.IsNetorkAdapterConnected Exception: " + e.Message.ToString());
    Utilities.DebugSolution.SetException("Utilies.NetworkCommunication.IsNetorkAdapterConnected", e);
}
return result;
```

Always having only one `return` in a method [is generally a good practice in C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118717/213), but it's not needed in C# and I think that using multiple returns would make this code simpler and clearer:

```
try
{
    progressBar.SetStatus("Quering network connections");  
    if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
    {
        status = String.Empty;
        return true;
    }

} catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Utilities.NetworkCommunication.IsNetorkAdapterConnected Exception: " + e.Message.ToString());
    Utilities.DebugSolution.SetException("Utilies.NetworkCommunication.IsNetorkAdapterConnected", e);
}

status = "Network adapter not connected";
return false;
```

---

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

You should use `using System.Net.NetworkInformation` for this.

---

```
if (IsNetorkAdapterConnected(ref status))
{


    try
    {
```

What's with the empty lines here? Empty lines are useful for separating parts of methods, but I don't see any reason for them here.

---

```
using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
    return CheckSpeed(String.Empty);
```

This is confusing. Why do you have the `stream` variable that's never used, and why do you close the stream only after `CheckSpeed` returns?

Also, have you considered using [the `HEAD` method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), which doesn't return any data at all? I think that would require you to use `WebRequest` instead of `WebClient`.